# How to pass id into navlink in react JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am fetching details from database and displaying on page and I want to create an edit button which after click can open that details in editable form. In my case that editable form is **(EMPLOYEEFORM)**.

Can you please suggest how to pass id into edit button so the button can take data to edit area.

I am having problem. Right not I have pass id to navlink but its gives me error like employee not found with this id. I am new to **reactjs**. I tried passing id value but its not acting properly and I am not so aware of passing id into navlink or button. Can you please suggest some direct code or and valuable link where can I update my knowledge.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './employees.css';
import routePaths from '../../shared/routePaths';
import { getEmployeeDetails } from '../../shared/services/apiService';
import { useParams, NavLink, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Descriptions , Card , Divider, Row , Col , Button} from 'antd';
import { isSuccess } from '../../shared/utils/jsHelper';

import { EditTwoTone } from '@ant-design/icons';
const { Meta } = Card;

const employeeDescription = () => {
    

    const {id} = useParams();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [empName, setEmpName] = useState([]);
    const [empEmail, setEmpEmail] = useState([]);
    const [empPhone, setEmpPhone] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (id) {
            getEmployee();
        }
    }, [id]);

    const getEmployee = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        getEmployeeDetails(id).then((resp) => {
            if (isSuccess(resp)) {
                const employee = resp.data.data;
                setEmployeeValues(employee);
            }
        }).finally(() => setLoading(false));
    };


    const setEmployeeValues = (employee) => {
        setEmpName(employee.empName);
        setEmpEmail(employee.empEmail);
        setEmpPhone(employee.empPhone);

    };


    return(
        <div>
            <Card 
                title="Employee Info" 
                extra={[
                    <NavLink to={'${routePaths.EMPLOYEEFORM}/${employee.id}'} className="lin">
                        <Button key="1">
                            <EditTwoTone twoToneColor="#000" /> Edit Employee Details
                        </Button>
                    </NavLink>,
                    <NavLink to={routePaths.EMPLOYEES} className="lin">
                        <Button key="2">
                            {'<<'} Back to Employee List
                        </Button>
                    </NavLink>,
                ]}
            >
                
                <h6>
                    <strong>Pesonal Details :</strong>
                </h6>
                
                <Divider />
                <Descriptions className="card-tis">
                    <Descriptions.Item label="Name ">{empName}</Descriptions.Item>
                    <Descriptions.Item label="Email ">{empEmail}</Descriptions.Item>
                    <Descriptions.Item label="Phone ">{empPhone}</Descriptions.Item>
                </Descriptions>
                 

            </Card>
        </div>
    );

};



export default employeeDescription;
```

Comment: Try `to={\`${routePaths.EMPLOYEEFORM}/${id}\`}`

Comment: You have to use template literals using `` instead of '', as it will interpolate your variable.

`<NavLink to={\`${routePaths.EMPLOYEEFORM}/${employee.id}\`} className="lin">
    <Button key="1">
                            <EditTwoTone twoToneColor="#000" /> Edit Employee Details
                        </Button>
                    </NavLink>`

Answer (score 3):

You can merge all of the states in one `state` of `employee` instead of maintaining state for each employee property.

In the provided code you are using `signle (')` quotes in the navlink instead of `backticks`. Which will not resolve the variable and you will get a plain string like `${routePaths.EMPLOYEEFORM}/${employee.id}`.

I have made few changes please try.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './employees.css';
import routePaths from '../../shared/routePaths';
import { getEmployeeDetails } from '../../shared/services/apiService';
import { useParams, NavLink, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Descriptions, Card, Divider, Row, Col, Button } from 'antd';
import { isSuccess } from '../../shared/utils/jsHelper';
import { EditTwoTone } from '@ant-design/icons';
const { Meta } = Card;
const employeeDescription = () => {

  const { id } = useParams();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [employee, setEmployee] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      getEmployee();
    }
  }, [id]);

  const getEmployee = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    getEmployeeDetails(id)
      .then((resp) => {
        if (isSuccess(resp)) {
          const employee = resp.data.data;
          setEmployee(employee);
        }
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <Card
        title="Employee Info"
        extra={[
          <NavLink to={`${routePaths.EMPLOYEEFORM}/${employee.id}`} className="lin">
            <Button key="1">
              <EditTwoTone twoToneColor="#000" /> Edit Employee Details
                        </Button>
          </NavLink>,
          <NavLink to={routePaths.EMPLOYEES} className="lin">
            <Button key="2">
              {'<<'} Back to Employee List
                        </Button>
          </NavLink>,
        ]}
      >
        <h6>
          <strong>Pesonal Details :</strong>
        </h6>
        <Divider />
        <Descriptions className="card-tis">
          <Descriptions.Item label="Name ">{employee.empName}</Descriptions.Item>
          <Descriptions.Item label="Email ">{empEmail.empEmail}</Descriptions.Item>
          <Descriptions.Item label="Phone ">{empPhone.empPhone}</Descriptions.Item>
        </Descriptions>

      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default employeeDescription;
```

Comment: Yes correct the same thing I have mentioned in my ans as well.

Comment: i corrected my code.. but there is no need of {employee.id} , there is only need of {id} and my mistake was that.